# How to set characters replacement limit with itertools replacement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need some limit for the all characters. I want to have max 2 of the same characters in the 7 places. Can I do that?

I get what I want with itertools `combination_with_replacement`. But I need a limit for every character.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

def combine(arr, s): 
    return list(combinations_with_replacement(symbols, s)) 

symbols = "Ga1SRT2"
max_length = 7 
set = 7
print(combine(symbols, set))
```

Example. Now I get one of `'G'`, `'G'`, `'G'`, `'a'`, `'S'`, `'S'`, `'R'` and I want to just get 2 `G`, not 3.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question is not quite clear. Is your restriction that you want *at most* 2 'G' characters in each combination or exactly 2? What about the other characters--is there no restriction on them, is there to be at most 2 of any character, does the restriction vary between the characters, or something else? Is code that generates more combinations than you want then removes some of them acceptable or not? Each of those choices results in a different solution.

Comment: Hi thanks Rory. I want to limit repetition for every symbol from symbols = "Ga1SRT2" to 2. They can be just one but if there is more than one I want to limit that on 2. So Ga1SRT2 is OK. GG1SRT2 is OK. But I don't want GGGSRT2. Or Ga1SRT2 is OK, aa1SRT2 is OK but aaaSRT2 is not OK.

Comment: Thanks, that does clarify your question somewhat. What about my last question? The only current answer generates more combinations than you needs and throws away the unwanted ones. Is that sufficient or do you want code that only generates the desired combinations?

Comment: I want all combination from area symbols = "Ga1SRT2" But I want to limit each characters on 2 repetitions. I don't want Ga, G1 and others short combination. I want only combination with 7 symbols and with 2 repetition only from the symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably not the most efficient because it computes then discards a lot of data but post-processing counting the elements and keeping only the ones where there are max 2 repeats work:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
import collections

def combine(arr, s):
    return [x for x in combinations_with_replacement(symbols, s) if max(collections.Counter(x).values()) <= 2]
```

The `if max(collections.Counter(x).values()) <= 2` in the list comprehension just keeps `x` if `x` members don't repeat more than twice.

We could also reuse a python equivalent of `combinations_with_replacement` (which is probably provided as native code on most platforms) provided in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) and perform a small & cheap algorithm optimization (note that we still need the filtering with `collections.Counter`)

```
def combinations_with_replacement(iterable, r):
    # combinations_with_replacement('ABC', 2) --> AA AB AC BB BC CC with tweak to avoid
    # to issue obvious data that is going to be filtered out
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if not n and r:
        return
    indices = [0] * r
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != n - 1:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i:] = [indices[i] + 1] * (r - i)
        if r - i < 3:
            yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

The last `yield` is done inconditionally in the original source. My proposal is to check if `r - i < 3`, as if it's greater, `indices` is guaranteed to contain the same index more than twice.

With your input, the standard `combinations_with_replacement` algorithm from `itertools` yields 1716 values that need filtering with element count.

With my modification, it only yields 1255 values, so  there are 25% less data to post-process. The replacement algorithm being pure python and not C, it's not sure that it's faster, though.

Comment: Thank you but I want all combination but limit with 2 repetition if there is. If not one or no one is just OK. But I don't want to have 3 and more repetition.

Comment: @Pijes: This code does exactly what you asked for. It may be less efficient than some other ways but it gets the job done and is very short and simple. To understand this code, check out the `Counter` class in the `collections` module.

Comment: I reduced to 4 items to get a smaller output and it works. I also tried to adapt the actual combinations_with_replacement source, but it's not trivial to filter items before they're issued.

Comment: @rory-daulton Yes thank you very much. At first I thinks that your code have always 2 repetition but than I looked close to results and see that you have right. Thank you so much one more time.

Comment: Can I ask one more question here? I get results all in one line. I found that you need to put somewhere /n for new line but I can't find where. And how to get rid of '  ' and , I do that in notepad++ but will be better if I can do this automatically

Comment: you're printing the tuples. If you use `"".join` on each tuple, you'll turn them back to strings.